# Keras - How to run loaded model on CPU

Tags: python, keras, gpu, cpu

I have keras with tensorflow backend that runs on GPU.  However, I am training an LSTM so instead I am training on the CPU.

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(50, len(train_x[0][0]))))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['acc'])
```

The problem I have is that when I save and load the model, the predict function for the loaded model performs very slowly.  After some timed tests I believe what is happening is that the loaded model is running on the GPU rather than the CPU, so it is slow.  I tried compiling the loaded model on the CPU however this does not speed things up:

```
model.save('test_model.h5')
new_model = load_model('test_model.h5')
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    new_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['acc'])
```

Is there a way to achieve the same speeds with the loaded model as with the newly trained model?  The newly trained model is almost five times faster.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the model with the device you want to use:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    new_model = load_model('test_model.h5')
```